# iOS - How To Make my view so that it doesn't respond to events

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uicontrol

i have asked this question      [Changing UIView To be instance from UIControl Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592957/ios-changing-uiview-to-be-instance-from-uicontrol-programmatically)       24 minutes ago but i he didn't benefit me , so i typing this question in another form hoping that you can help me

i have a view that its class is from UIControl (so of course it will receive events)
and i have a button that i want it to change my view to normal UIView instance (so of course it will receive events)

so how to make that

i want the code if changing the view to UIView here

```
-(IBAction)pauseButton:(id)sender
{
   //here
}
```

i want the code of changing the view to UIControl here

```
-(IBAction)playButton:(id)sender
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not change an object's class in objective-c. If you just want the control to stop receiving touches, you can use:

```
 [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]
```

Comment: i think there was a checbbox for this in the view properties on the  right side of the interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly make sure you have an `IBOUTLET` for that view or object and make sure it is connected.**

**For example we will say the view is called** `the_view`

Now you can over uncheck the UserInteractionEnabled checkbox within the interface builders property tab of that object or type a line of code. The second option is better if you want the button to raise the event of stopping touches being allowed.

**For the first option I have uploaded a video showing the basic steps:**

[Click Here For tutorial](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50751529/Screen%20Recording%202.mov)

**For the second on option you can use this code:**

```
the_view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

**Or if you are trying to hide your default view simply use:**

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

**or as noted in the answer above:**

```
[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]
```